# Он относится к ней "ревностно" или "ревниво"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

**Многие сейчас употребляют слово "ревностно" в значении "ревниво".** Допустимо ли употребление этих однокоренных слов в качестве синонимов?

Comment: Земля слухом полнится, что:

1) многие [черепашки-ниндзя] сейчас употребляют слово "ревностно" в значении "ревниво",

2) многие [мишки Гамми] сейчас употребляют слово "ревниво" в значении "ревностно".

Comment: А ещё они говорят "займи мне пару тысяч" вместо "одолжи мне пару тысяч".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слова "ревнивый и ревностный" являются родственными с точки зрения этимологии, так как происходят от одного и.-е. корня re и одной о.-с. основы rьvьn.  Корень re обозначает движение, стремление, в современном языке это значение  в чистом виде сохраняет  глагол "ринуться".

С 11 века в др.-рус. языке отмечаются слова рьвьн - усердие, рвение, рьвьный - исполненный усердия, рьвьнивый - усердный. Они обозначали рвение и усердие во всем - в деятельности, в заботе, во вражде и, наконец, в любви. С 17 века значения слов ревнивый  и ревностный расходятся. В 1627 году "ревнивый" толкуется уже только как "ревнуючий жонѣ  от иного".

В современном языке РЕВНОСТНЫЙ - это усердный, проявляющий рвение, а РЕВНИВЫЙ мучительно сомневается в чьей-то верности и любви или придирчиво-настороженно поглядывает на соперников, опасаясь чужого успеха. Ревности в делах он больше не проявляет (устар. значение).

Таким образом, можно представить следующую семантическую схему образования слов: (1)рвение/усердие- ревностный и (2) рвение/усердие - ревнивый - ревность.

Материал соответствует историко-этимологическому словарю Черных.

Answer (score 3):

Происхождение слова ревнивый неясно. По одной версии, оно восходит к  глаголу реветь. По другой – к глаголам ринуться, реять, имеющих общий компонент значения «приходить в движение». Отсюда, возможно, первоначальное значение ревнивый«соревнующийся, соперничающий.
В современном русском языке ревнивый соотносится прежде всего со словом ревность. Ревнивый значит склонный к ревности, охваченный ревностью (ревнивый муж) или выражающий ревность (ревнивые взгляды). Но с этим значением как раз всё понятно.
А вот в контекстах типа «ревнивое отношение к карьере друга» значение прилагательного уже иное: «придирчиво-настороженный. Ещё один оттенок: Ревниво относиться к своему делу; Ревниво оберегать секреты мастерства, т.е. заботливо, усердно, старательно.
Такое значение имеет и другое прилагательное с корнем ревн-: ревностный. Согласно словарю, ревностный  «относящийся к чему-л. с рвением и усердием; старательный, заботливый, усердный’. Ревностными могут быть ценители искусства, поборники справедливости, блюстители порядка. Прилагательное ревностный может употребляться и с неодушевлёнными существительными: ревностное отношение к делу, ревностная служба. Производные от слова ревностный – наречие ревностно (ревностно относиться к своим обязанностям, ревностно взяться за новое дело) и существительное ревностность (ревностность защитников реформ).
Ревнивый и ревностный, ревниво и ревностно  слова-паронимы. Их не следует путать. Напр., в предложении У священнослужителей очень скептическое, ревностное отношение к экстрасенсам (АиФ) слово ревностное использовано ошибочно вместо ревнивое. См. также: Мужчины относятся к успехам женщин очень ревностно (вместо ревниво). Источник: Портал для журналистов " Живое слово".

Comment: Значит, во фразе "он ревностно к ней относится", которую часто произносят, когда хотят сказать, что он её ревнует, слово "ревностно" употреблено ошибочно?

Comment: Конечно. В данном случае путают два понятия, обозначенных похожими словами. Надо говорить "Он ревниво к ней относится", а лучше "Он ее ревнует"